# Extracting variables from the WorldClim database using raster in R

Tags: raster, r

I am extracting temperature information using the `getData` function from the `raster` package.

```
bio1 <- getData('worldclim', var="bio", res = 0.5, lon=1, lat=-77)

bio2 <- getData('worldclim', var="bio", res = 0.5, lon=7, lat=-70)
```

The variable bio `var=bio` , means it is extraction 19 layers of different bioclimatic variables at the lon/lat coordinates provided.

The problem is that if I get the mean of these layers for both `bio1` and `bio2`, even though they are from different lat/lon coordinates, they are the same. And I am using the finest resolution `res = 0.5` :

```
> cellStats(bio1,stat = "mean")
   bio1_46    bio2_46    bio3_46    bio4_46    bio5_46    bio6_46    bio7_46    bio8_46    bio9_46   bio10_46   bio11_46 
 159.38445  146.23495   54.29901 4262.23057  292.49362   23.63659  268.85703  178.42543  132.43352  211.26331  102.22708 
  bio12_46   bio13_46   bio14_46   bio15_46   bio16_46   bio17_46   bio18_46   bio19_46 
 416.39054   61.81748   13.82139   45.91476  165.43986   48.51057  129.29831   72.57548 
> cellStats(bio2,stat = "mean")
   bio1_46    bio2_46    bio3_46    bio4_46    bio5_46    bio6_46    bio7_46    bio8_46    bio9_46   bio10_46   bio11_46 
 159.38445  146.23495   54.29901 4262.23057  292.49362   23.63659  268.85703  178.42543  132.43352  211.26331  102.22708 
  bio12_46   bio13_46   bio14_46   bio15_46   bio16_46   bio17_46   bio18_46   bio19_46 
 416.39054   61.81748   13.82139   45.91476  165.43986   48.51057  129.29831   72.57548
```

From the manual I understood that `cellStats` would get the mean for the cells of each of my layers. But maybe it is doing something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `getData` downloads tiles and the two locations you provided belong to the same tile.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So if I want to get the datapoint at that lat/lon coordinate, what should I do? Is it possible to get tat using `raster`?

Comment: `extract(bio1, y = data.frame(lon = c(1,7), lat = c(-77, -70)))` should do the trick, but it looks like worldclim does not go below -60 degrees latitude. So your points don't intersect with your layer.

Comment: Which makes sense since there is no land other than Antartica that low, and worldclim is for 'global land areas'

Comment: So, I should first use `getData` to get the tile and then I use `extract` to get my data at the exact lat/lon point?

Comment: @JavierM88 That's right

Comment: Thanks again!, but I am still finding some issues: I now downloaded a new tile within the boundaries of worldclim. If I only want the variables at specific lon/lat points. Should I use `y=data.frame(lon,lat)`? Why do I get a different result if I use `y=c(lon,lat)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52001/discussion-between-javierm88-and-loic-dutrieux).

Comment: @JavierM88 using `y=c(lon,lat)` will give you cell values for cell indices `lon` and `lat`, not coordinates

Comment: OK, so the dataframe would specify lat/lon coordinates. Thank you SO much.